# how do I check if a specific string exists in the response, and set a user defined variable to true or false

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to determine if a specific string exists in a HTTP response.  If it does, I want to set a user defined variable to TRUE, and if it does not, I want to set it to FALSE.  I do not want to pass/fail the test based on this.  I just want to know if the response has the string or not.  Then, once I have that answer stored in my user defined variable, I will use that variable in the jmeter IF controller to perform other actions based on the answer.

I have tried using the beanshell assertion with the following code, but my pre-defined user variable, called stringExists, is not getting updated to correctly reflect if the response has the string or not:

```
vars.get("stringExists");

if (new String(ResponseData).contains("this is the string I expect")) {
    vars.put("stringExists","TRUE");
}
else {
    vars.put("stringExists","FALSE");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you can use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) in order to "see" the generated variable:

[image]

Also be informed that [starting with JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so you should consider switching to the [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion). As there is no `ResponseData` shorthand there you will need to amend a code a little bit:

```
if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("this is the string I expect")) {
    vars.put("stringExists","TRUE");
}
else {
    vars.put("stringExists","FALSE");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitri.  I added the Debug Sampler, switched to JSR223 Assertion and ran the script again, and now it works!  So, I switched back to the Beanshell Assertion I was using, and it works as well.  At this point, I'm not sure why it was failing for me.